# geocoding address from form

Tags: php, geocoding

Im using this form to geocode addresses on user input. How do I get only the lat and lon not the entire array printed to page. Here is page 1.php :

```
<form action="2.php" method="get">
<input type="text" name="adress" /><br /> 
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

page 2.php :

```
First Name: <?php echo $_GET["adress"]; ?><br /> 
<?php        
$address= $_GET["adress"];
$result=file_get_contents("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=" . urlencode($address) );
$geocodedinfo=json_decode($result);

print_r($geocodedinfo);
?>
```

Comment: dont use print_r just echo the array elements you want to see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to print out the array that you want. I would like to see the results of your full array though.
Lets say that you get this array lat[], long[], etc[], etc[]..

```
print_r($geocodedinfo['lat']. $geocodedinfo['long']);
```

Comment: http://nickshanekearney.com/geo/1.php
Here is my test page where you can see the results of the array.

Answer (score 0):

First you really should make sure the result completed OK first by checking the result status. That lives in `$geocodedinfo['status']` which should contain `OK`.

Your lat/long set can be displayed by

```
if ( $geocodedinfo['status'] == 'OK' )  {
print $geocodedinfo['results']['geometry']['location']['lat']; 
print $geocodedinfo['results']['geometry']['location']['long'];  }
```

You can see the full specs on the JSON-formatted response at the [Google Geocoding API site](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/?csw=1#JSON)